# The ouput Vo graph that is clipped

Tags: ac, diodes, voltage-clipping

[image: This is the Question]

this is the circuit I am considering everything ideal. according to me it will clip the AC voltage from both cycles but the battery polarity of 15V with D2 is confusing me.

According to me the output will be like this
Please help me in understanding if I am write and correct  me if you think its wrong and please guide.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If all components are ideal, the circuit has a serious problem. Look at this partial diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjfS0n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A current will flow from BAT1 to BAT2, not limited by any resistance! So this is a perfect recipe for fireworks.

Even if the components are not ideal, you still have a serious problem. The diodes will overheat and/or the batteries may be overloaded.